# How hike(version- 4.6.0.86) is showing floating action button on whatsapp application

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-applicationinfo

I just started my whatsApp messenger, it shows floating action button of hike with loads of stickers. 
WhatsApp version: 2.12.250
hike Version    : 4.6.0.86

Android Phone : Moto E(5.0 Lollypop).
What kind of permission hike is using to show his floating action on other app page.

How can i achieve this in my Android apps ??

Comment: Why negative marking on this question. Any explanation ?? It is directly discouraging me to write any question on forum ??. When any body giving negative point at least mention something so that developer can improve or new stack-overflow joiner can improve.